# Multiple ID selectors separated by a space, not a comma

Tags: css, css-selectors

For once, I found an issue that I couldn't find an answer to by searching stackoverflow.

For the Vantage theme in WordPress, I came across the following rule:

```
#search-icon #search-icon-icon {
  /* rules here */
}
```

What is the name of this type of combination of selectors, and how does it work? I'm assuming that it applies to an element with the #search-icon-icon style applied, nested within an element where #search-icon is applied.

Comment: It would be great help to you if you read up on how css works, tutorials or some free online lessons

Comment: @Huangism Notice the part where I said "For once, I found an issue that I couldn't find an answer to by searching stackoverflow."

Comment: This site is not a place for tutorials, I am sure you can find some decent ones if you google css tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

From [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors):

> At times, authors may want selectors to match an element that is the descendant of another element in the document tree. Descendant selectors express such a relationship in a pattern. A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by white space. A descendant selector of the form `A B` matches when an element `B` is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element `A`.

You are completely right about its meaning.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen it applied to Type Selectors before, I guess I was just thrown by seeing it with ID Selectors.

Comment: You're welcome! Please close up this question if it is resolved.